# Setting Working Directory as subfolder in default WD

Tags: r

Just started learning R (I have no coding experience) and wanted to change my WD from `/documents` to `/documents/R`.

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Vincent/Documents"
> setwd(paste(getwd(),"/R",sep=""))
>
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Vincent/Documents/R"
> save.image("C:\\Users\\Vincent\\Documents\\R\\.RData")
```

Am I supposed to save afterwards? I've tried saving in both `/Documents` and `/R`. After I save and close, if I just open rGUI from windows, `getwd()` will give me just `/Documents`.

But if I open the workspace file that was saved in `/R`, then `getwd()` will correctly give me `/R`. Do I have to always open R from the workspace file to get it to us `/R` as the WD?

Comment: My preferred way to start R in a working directory I like is to manage projects in RStudio and use *.Rproj.

Answer (score 0):

R's working directory will be set to the place where it is run from. Here's a watered down example

```
romunov@computerName C:\Users\romunov
> R

R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

...

> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/romunov"
> q("no")

romunov@computerName C:\Users\romunov
> cd Documents

romunov@computerName C:\Users\romunov\Documents
> R

R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

...

> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/romunov/Documents"
```

If you are willing to use RStudio, saving a project (and then opening it) will make your `getwd()` point to where the project was established.

Comment: What are the benefits of RStudio vs. the standard GUI? or rather, which do you recommend?

Comment: @VincentMQ it's a matter of personal preference. For me, however, I like to have a proper IDE, even if it's lacking a few features characteristic of mature IDEs in other languages. My suggestion would be to use IDE, any IDE.